# What is the difference between TRANSLATE and REPLACE in sql?

Tags: database, rdbms

select translate('flipflop','fl','h') from dual;

select replace('flipflop','fl','h') from dual;

These two queries give the same output,then why do we have different commands for carrying out the same operation?

Answer (score 2):

Translate translate the string byte by byte

The a is replaced with an e, the h has no complement and is dropped. 
SELECT TRANSLATE('So What', 'ah', 'e')
FROM dual;

Replace only occurance of word with specified word if match found like o with ay

SELECT REPLACE('So What', 'o', 'ay')
FROM dual;
UG

see https://community.oracle.com/thread/676170

Comment: Thank You :).That surely answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
         REPLACE                                 TRANSLATE


Replaces entire string at a time      Replaces character one-to-one basis


Returns string if no match found      Returns null if no match found
```